# How do I use pd.read_html and loop through many different urls and store each set of dfs into a master list of dfs?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I was wondering how to pull tickers from an excel file, load a bunch of websites and run pd.read_html on each website in order to get a big list of dfs that contained the tables of each page?

This is my list of tickerss:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16kdjtOlV1M_rDnM73lPi6ZcMvowQPmtjKu6bYTXK588/edit?usp=sharing

This is my current code:

```
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()

df_list = []

for ticker in tickers_list:
    df_list[ticker] = pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)

print(df_list)
```

And then when I do that, I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `ticker` isn't an integer, it's a string. if you want to index a collection of values with strings, use a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()

df_list = []

for ticker in range(len(tickers_list)):
    df_list[ticker] = pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)

print(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)


for ticker in tickers_list:
    data[ticker] = pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)


print(data)
```